# Retrieving and Parsing Text From Specific Webpage Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, text

I need to retrieve the text from a specific website. However, I only need a few parts of it. How can I accomplish this using swift.

I have found the following in objective-c, but am not sure it provides how to reference it from a specific site:

```
NSString *webString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerText"];
NSScanner *stringScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:webString];
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] init];
while ([stringScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

[stringScanner scanUpToString:@"Start of the text you want" intoString:null];
[stringScanner scanUpToString:@"End of the text you want" intoString:&content];
}`
```

I have put an example of what I mean below: [image]

Again, I would like to accomplish this using Swift.

Comment: First off, you need to decide what parts of the HTML you require. Then you will use NScanner to filter out for the parts of the Full HTML you need. Also. You will need to use NString constructor "stringWithContentsOfURL" passing it the NSURL of the site you require. This will be your full HTML of the page

Comment: @Harvey Could you provide an example? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

If your HTML was easily targetable with identifiers or class names, I would suggest using a library such as [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna). But I've had a look at your page and the text you need is lost amidst an ocean of divs...

So I've quickly hacked a way to get your text with `componentsSeparatedByString`: I'm cutting the HTML in blocks until I get to the part we're interested in.

Note that it's far from being the most efficient way: instead of using `componentsSeparatedByString` you should come with a way of identifying the HTML block you want and search for it with NSScanner.

That being said, here's my example of a working hack, tested in a Playground:

```
enum CustomErrors : String, ErrorType {
    case InvalidURL = "Invalid URL"
}

do {
    let str = "http://www.golfwrx.com/328370/mizuno-to-offer-custom-grips-at-no-additional-charge/"
    guard let url = NSURL(string: str) else { throw CustomErrors.InvalidURL }
    let html = try String(contentsOfURL: url)
    let separator1 = "<div class='mailmunch-forms-before-post' style='display: none !important;'></div><p>"
    let temp = html.componentsSeparatedByString(separator1)
    let separator2 = "</p>\n<p>"
    let temp2 = temp[1].componentsSeparatedByString(separator2)
    let separator3 = "</p><div class='mailmunch-forms-in-post-middle'"
    let separated = temp2[1].componentsSeparatedByString(separator3)
    let result = separated[0]
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

*Note: my example is in Swift 2 (Xcode 7).*

Comment: +1 for suggesting usage of a library. Depending on application. Readability may be a suitable approach also

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the specifics, I'm an Objective-C guy. but, here is an example of how to use NString to get the contents of a websites HTML

```
NSString *url = @"http://www.example.com"; // Your URL
NSURL *urlRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:url]; // Make a request with your URL
NSError *err = nil; // Error handler

NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlRequest encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err]; // Try to get the HTML in the string

if(err)
{
    //Do something as it didn't work! Maybe a connection problem
}
else
{
    // Use NScanner on html string
}
```

http://nshipster.com/nsscanner/ is a good place to learn about NScanner for swift

**EDIT: Here is the above translated to swift**

```
var err: NSError? // Error handler
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com") // NSURL, put your website URL in here
let string = NSString(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &err) // String will now hold your HTML
// Now use NScanner (See Link) to parse the HTML output
```

My swift is rusty. but this might help you. This is *roughly* translated but outlines exactly what you need

Comment: I still do not understand. I just need it in swift. I have found objective-c resources already. Thank you though.

Comment: Added some Swift to assist